# How to restrict all services to single domain in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, domain, service

Someone has pointed an unknown domain to my server's IP address likely via A records. I would like to reject access to ALL services (httpd, ssh, mail, etc.) from this domain and only allow requests from my domain. I want to make it so when I connect to that domain it's completely rejected from my server. I can disallow access from HTTP by changing my web server settings, but I want to do this for every single type of connection.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The only service that has any knowledge of the calling "domain" is HTTP. For that, just create a name-based virtual host that throws a 404 error or similar. For the other services there's really nothing you can do, as SSH/SMTP/etc. do not have an equivalent of HTTP's `Host` header.

If this traffic is not causing a problem, then just ignore it. It's not worth worrying about.